# Eclipse: Keep Metadata Subscription on Password Update

Tags: metadata, eclipse

Is there a way to prevent Eclipse losing metadata component subscription when updating the Salesforce password?

I am referring to the screen below, which when updating the project to include the new password becomes empty:

[image]

This happens for me on both Juno and Kepler, on different machines

Comment: which eclipse you are using. Because in my eclipse kepler I never lost the refernce when I update password.

Comment: Juno and Kepler, on different machines.